# Assembly: list all symbols of an application

Tags: assembly, symbols

I programmed an really simply code:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp
//
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"

void abc() {
    printf("ABCDEF");
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello");
    printf("2ndString Here");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the result of Windbg:

```
0:000> x ConsoleApplication1!*
00007ff6`dc5335b0 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_current_native_startup_state = initialized (0n2)
00007ff6`dc533008 ConsoleApplication1!__security_cookie_complement = 0xffff6a36`95faba8f
00007ff6`dc531e90 ConsoleApplication1!_guard_dispatch_icall_nop = 0xff ''
00007ff6`dc5321d0 ConsoleApplication1!__xp_a = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc532650 ConsoleApplication1!__rtc_taa = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc532190 ConsoleApplication1!__guard_dispatch_icall_fptr = 0x00007ff6`dc531e90
00007ff6`dc532640 ConsoleApplication1!__rtc_iaa = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc5335d8 ConsoleApplication1!module_local_at_quick_exit_table = struct _onexit_table_t
00007ff6`dc532198 ConsoleApplication1!__xc_a = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc532198 ConsoleApplication1!__xc_a = <function> *[]
00007ff6`dc533030 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_ucrt_dll_is_in_use = 0n1
00007ff6`dc533030 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_ucrt_dll_is_in_use = 0n1
00007ff6`dc5321b8 ConsoleApplication1!pre_c_initializer = 0x00007ff6`dc531154
00007ff6`dc533020 ConsoleApplication1!__memcpy_nt_iters = 0n-1
00007ff6`dc5321a0 ConsoleApplication1!pre_cpp_initializer = 0x00007ff6`dc531220
00007ff6`dc533630 ConsoleApplication1!__dyn_tls_init_callback = 0x00000000`00000000
00007ff6`dc5321c8 ConsoleApplication1!__xi_z = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc5321c8 ConsoleApplication1!__xi_z = <function> *[]
00007ff6`dc5335c0 ConsoleApplication1!module_local_atexit_table = struct _onexit_table_t
00007ff6`dc5330e0 ConsoleApplication1!GS_ContextRecord = struct _CONTEXT
00007ff6`dc5321e0 ConsoleApplication1!__xt_a = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc533618 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_debugger_hook_flag = 0n0
00007ff6`dc5335f0 ConsoleApplication1!is_initialized_as_dll = false
00007ff6`dc53301c ConsoleApplication1!__isa_enabled = 0n46
00007ff6`dc5335b8 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_native_startup_lock = 0x00000000`00000000
00007ff6`dc5321c0 ConsoleApplication1!post_pgo_initializer = 0x00007ff6`dc531210
00007ff6`dc532188 ConsoleApplication1!__guard_check_icall_fptr = 0x00007ff6`dc531d58
00007ff6`dc532188 ConsoleApplication1!__guard_check_icall_fptr = 0x00007ff6`dc531d58
00007ff6`dc532188 ConsoleApplication1!__guard_check_icall_fptr = 0x00007ff6`dc531d58
00007ff6`dc532680 ConsoleApplication1!$xdatasym = 0x01 ''
00007ff6`dc532740 ConsoleApplication1!$xdatasym = 0x01 ''
00007ff6`dc5321b0 ConsoleApplication1!__xi_a = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc5321b0 ConsoleApplication1!__xi_a = <function> *[]
00007ff6`dc5321f0 ConsoleApplication1!GS_ExceptionPointers = struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS
00007ff6`dc532648 ConsoleApplication1!__rtc_izz = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc5321a8 ConsoleApplication1!__xc_z = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc5321a8 ConsoleApplication1!__xc_z = <function> *[]
00007ff6`dc533014 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_default_matherr = 0n1
00007ff6`dc533014 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_default_matherr = 0n1
00007ff6`dc5321d8 ConsoleApplication1!__xp_z = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc532658 ConsoleApplication1!__rtc_tzz = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc533040 ConsoleApplication1!GS_ExceptionRecord = struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD
00007ff6`dc532290 ConsoleApplication1!_load_config_used = struct _IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY64
00007ff6`dc533010 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_native_dllmain_reason = 0xffffffff
00007ff6`dc533000 ConsoleApplication1!__security_cookie = 0x000095c9`6a054570
00007ff6`dc533018 ConsoleApplication1!__isa_available = 0n5
00007ff6`dc53361c ConsoleApplication1!__favor = 0n6
00007ff6`dc5321e8 ConsoleApplication1!__xt_z = <function> *[1]
00007ff6`dc533600 ConsoleApplication1!__type_info_root_node = struct __type_info_node
00007ff6`dc533628 ConsoleApplication1!__dyn_tls_dtor_callback = 0x00000000`00000000
00007ff6`dc5313c8 ConsoleApplication1!__raise_securityfailure (struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *)
00007ff6`dc5318a0 ConsoleApplication1!_get_startup_commit_mode (void)
00007ff6`dc5318f8 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_get_dyn_tls_dtor_callback (void)
00007ff6`dc531e90 ConsoleApplication1!_guard_dispatch_icall_nop (void)
00007ff6`dc531010 ConsoleApplication1!_vfprintf_l (struct _iobuf *, char *, struct __crt_locale_pointers *, char *)
00007ff6`dc531ae4 ConsoleApplication1!_RTC_Initialize (void)
00007ff6`dc5318a0 ConsoleApplication1!_get_startup_thread_locale_mode (void)
00007ff6`dc531d4c ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_is_ucrt_dll_in_use (void)
00007ff6`dc5310e0 ConsoleApplication1!main (void)
00007ff6`dc531758 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_uninitialize_crt (bool, bool)
00007ff6`dc531e1c ConsoleApplication1!__GSHandlerCheckCommon (void *, struct _DISPATCHER_CONTEXT *, struct _GS_HANDLER_DATA *)
00007ff6`dc531698 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_is_nonwritable_in_current_image (void *)
00007ff6`dc531580 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_initialize_crt (__scrt_module_type)
00007ff6`dc531a9c ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_set_unhandled_exception_filter (void)
00007ff6`dc531d58 ConsoleApplication1!_initialize_denormal_control (void)
00007ff6`dc5317d4 ConsoleApplication1!atexit (<function> *)
00007ff6`dc5318bc ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_stub_for_acrt_initialize (void)
00007ff6`dc531b30 ConsoleApplication1!_RTC_Terminate (void)
00007ff6`dc531dfc ConsoleApplication1!__GSHandlerCheck (struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD *, void *, struct _CONTEXT *, struct _DISPATCHER_CONTEXT *)
00007ff6`dc5318a4 ConsoleApplication1!_get_startup_file_mode (void)
00007ff6`dc5313b4 ConsoleApplication1!mainCRTStartup (void)
00007ff6`dc531060 ConsoleApplication1!printf (char *)
00007ff6`dc5318c8 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_initialize_default_local_stdio_options (void)
00007ff6`dc5315cc ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_initialize_onexit_tables (__scrt_module_type)
00007ff6`dc531eb0 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_is_nonwritable_in_current_image$filt$0 (void)
00007ff6`dc5318bc ConsoleApplication1!_should_initialize_environment (void)
00007ff6`dc531154 ConsoleApplication1!pre_c_initialization (void)
00007ff6`dc5318a0 ConsoleApplication1!_matherr (struct _exception *)
00007ff6`dc531544 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_acquire_startup_lock (void)
00007ff6`dc5318a0 ConsoleApplication1!_get_startup_new_mode (void)
00007ff6`dc531a48 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_is_managed_app (void)
00007ff6`dc531aac ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_unhandled_exception_filter (struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *)
00007ff6`dc531d58 ConsoleApplication1!_initialize_invalid_parameter_handler (void)
00007ff6`dc531b84 ConsoleApplication1!__isa_available_init (void)
00007ff6`dc5318e4 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_is_user_matherr_present (void)
00007ff6`dc531898 ConsoleApplication1!_get_startup_argv_mode (void)
00007ff6`dc531130 ConsoleApplication1!__security_check_cookie (void)
00007ff6`dc5314d0 ConsoleApplication1!capture_previous_context (struct _CONTEXT *)
00007ff6`dc531220 ConsoleApplication1!pre_cpp_initialization (void)
00007ff6`dc5318f0 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_get_dyn_tls_init_callback (void)
00007ff6`dc531d58 ConsoleApplication1!_guard_check_icall_nop (unsigned int64)
00007ff6`dc5318bc ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_stub_for_acrt_uninitialize (bool)
00007ff6`dc53123c ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_common_main_seh (void)
00007ff6`dc5318ac ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_initialize_type_info (void)
00007ff6`dc531734 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_release_startup_lock (bool)
00007ff6`dc531110 ConsoleApplication1!__vcrt_va_start_verify_argument_type<char const * __ptr64 const> (void)
00007ff6`dc531900 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_fastfail (unsigned int)
00007ff6`dc531e92 ConsoleApplication1!`__scrt_common_main_seh'::`1'::filt$0 (void)
00007ff6`dc5318c0 ConsoleApplication1!__local_stdio_scanf_options (void)
00007ff6`dc5317ec ConsoleApplication1!__security_init_cookie (void)
00007ff6`dc531b7c ConsoleApplication1!_guard_check_icall (unsigned int64)
00007ff6`dc5313fc ConsoleApplication1!__report_gsfailure (unsigned int64)
00007ff6`dc531000 ConsoleApplication1!__local_stdio_printf_options (void)
00007ff6`dc531784 ConsoleApplication1!_onexit (<function> *)
00007ff6`dc531210 ConsoleApplication1!post_pgo_initialization (void)
00007ff6`dc5318a0 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_initialize_winrt (void)
00007ff6`dc532138 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__get_initial_narrow_environment = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532038 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_GetCurrentThreadId = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531d7e ConsoleApplication1!configure_narrow_argv (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc531dc0 ConsoleApplication1!c_exit (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc531d9c ConsoleApplication1!exit (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc5320e8 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__seh_filter_exe = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc5320f0 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__crt_atexit = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc5320d8 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_terminate = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532128 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__initterm_e = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532158 ConsoleApplication1!api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0_NULL_THUNK_DATA = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc5320d0 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__initialize_onexit_table = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc5320a0 ConsoleApplication1!api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0_NULL_THUNK_DATA = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531d78 ConsoleApplication1!_setusermatherr (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc531df6 ConsoleApplication1!IsProcessorFeaturePresent (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532180 ConsoleApplication1!api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0_NULL_THUNK_DATA = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532080 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_memset = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531d90 ConsoleApplication1!initterm (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc531da2 ConsoleApplication1!exit (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532010 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_UnhandledExceptionFilter = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531d60 ConsoleApplication1!_C_specific_handler (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532178 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__set_fmode = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532100 ConsoleApplication1!_imp___p___argv = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531dba ConsoleApplication1!cexit (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc531df0 ConsoleApplication1!terminate (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc531dcc ConsoleApplication1!configthreadlocale (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532788 ConsoleApplication1!_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0 = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532120 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_exit = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531dc6 ConsoleApplication1!register_thread_local_exe_atexit_callback (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532060 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_GetCurrentProcess = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532088 ConsoleApplication1!_imp___C_specific_handler = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532070 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_RtlCaptureContext = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532078 ConsoleApplication1!KERNEL32_NULL_THUNK_DATA = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531d84 ConsoleApplication1!initialize_narrow_environment (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc5320b8 ConsoleApplication1!_imp___setusermatherr = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532040 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_GetCurrentProcessId = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc53279c ConsoleApplication1!_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0 = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531dde ConsoleApplication1!initialize_onexit_table (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532108 ConsoleApplication1!_imp___p___argc = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532050 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_IsProcessorFeaturePresent = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc5320b0 ConsoleApplication1!api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0_NULL_THUNK_DATA = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532130 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__initterm = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532760 ConsoleApplication1!_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0 = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc5327b0 ConsoleApplication1!_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0 = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532118 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__exit = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532058 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_TerminateProcess = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531de4 ConsoleApplication1!register_onexit_function (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532020 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_IsDebuggerPresent = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531dae ConsoleApplication1!_p___argc (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532110 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__register_thread_local_exe_atexit_callback = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532090 ConsoleApplication1!VCRUNTIME140_NULL_THUNK_DATA = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532168 ConsoleApplication1!_imp___stdio_common_vfprintf = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532170 ConsoleApplication1!_imp___acrt_iob_func = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532030 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_GetSystemTimeAsFileTime = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc5320e0 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__set_app_type = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531dd2 ConsoleApplication1!set_new_mode (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc5320a8 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__configthreadlocale = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532000 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_RtlLookupFunctionEntry = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532048 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_QueryPerformanceCounter = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531dd8 ConsoleApplication1!_p__commode (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532140 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__initialize_narrow_environment = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532028 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_InitializeSListHead = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532008 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_RtlVirtualUnwind = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc533620 ConsoleApplication1!`__local_stdio_printf_options'::`2'::_OptionsStorage = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532018 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_GetModuleHandleW = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531d96 ConsoleApplication1!initterm_e (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc5320c0 ConsoleApplication1!api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0_NULL_THUNK_DATA = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531d6c ConsoleApplication1!seh_filter_exe (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532098 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__set_new_mode = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532774 ConsoleApplication1!_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0 = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531db4 ConsoleApplication1!_p___argv (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc531d8a ConsoleApplication1!get_initial_narrow_environment (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532068 ConsoleApplication1!_imp_SetUnhandledExceptionFilter = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc5327c4 ConsoleApplication1!_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_KERNEL32 = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532160 ConsoleApplication1!_imp___p__commode = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc5320f8 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__cexit = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531da8 ConsoleApplication1!set_fmode (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc532150 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__register_onexit_function = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531dea ConsoleApplication1!crt_atexit (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc53274c ConsoleApplication1!_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_VCRUNTIME140 = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc532148 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__configure_narrow_argv = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc5320c8 ConsoleApplication1!_imp__c_exit = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531d72 ConsoleApplication1!set_app_type (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc531d66 ConsoleApplication1!memset (<no parameter info>)
00007ff6`dc5327d8 ConsoleApplication1!_NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc533610 ConsoleApplication1!`__local_stdio_scanf_options'::`2'::_OptionsStorage = <no type information>
00007ff6`dc531337 ConsoleApplication1!invoke_main =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_common_main_seh+fb
00007ff6`dc53119e ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_narrow_argv_policy::configure_argv =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!pre_c_initialization+4a
00007ff6`dc5311e7 ConsoleApplication1!initialize_environment =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!pre_c_initialization+93
00007ff6`dc5313b8 ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_common_main =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!mainCRTStartup+4
00007ff6`dc531551 ConsoleApplication1!NtCurrentTeb =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_acquire_startup_lock+d
00007ff6`dc531618 ConsoleApplication1!__crt_fast_encode_pointer =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_initialize_onexit_tables+4c
00007ff6`dc53161f ConsoleApplication1!__crt_rotate_pointer_value =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_initialize_onexit_tables+53
00007ff6`dc53169f ConsoleApplication1!is_potentially_valid_image_base =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_is_nonwritable_in_current_image+7
00007ff6`dc5316d5 ConsoleApplication1!find_pe_section =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_is_nonwritable_in_current_image+3d
00007ff6`dc53178a ConsoleApplication1!__crt_fast_decode_pointer =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!_onexit+6
00007ff6`dc5317a0 ConsoleApplication1!__crt_rotate_pointer_value =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!_onexit+1c
00007ff6`dc531929 ConsoleApplication1!__crt_debugger_hook =  (inline caller) ConsoleApplication1!__scrt_fastfail+29
```

What means the symbol list? What generates a symbol? Every method? Class? Why isn't there ConsoleApplication1!abc available?

There are a huge number of other symbols.. can they be seperated and classified (eg mainCRTStartup and the ConsoleApplication1!main belong to executables)?
Are there differences in kernel programming?

(Code optimization is deactivated.)

Comment: The C runtime library is responsible for those other symbols, along with stack checking and other value-add features of Microsoft's compiler. If optimizations are disabled, you should see abc(), though. Possibly you're only looking at public symbols, or you have compiled optimizations off but linker optimizations on?

Comment: Does "not optimised" include compiling unused functions or variables? Is "unnecessary" same as "optimised"?

Comment: As to "really simply code" - note that "stdafx.h" pulls in hundreds of thousands of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What means the symbol list?

The symbols list is the list of "symbols" in a file - of course.

"Symbols" are items in object files that have an address (or - sometimes - an absolute value).

The main use of symbols is to tell the linker where some item (function, variable, constant...) is located in an object file:

When some machine code accesses a variable or calls a function the code has to "know" the address of the variable or function. When creating an object file from source code these addresses are not known, yet; especially if a function or variable is defined in another object file than the code accessing it.

Therefore a dummy address is used when the object file is created; the linker later has to replace the dummy address by the real one.

The information about which variable is located at which address is stored in the "symbols" of an object file.

The symbols of an .EXE files are typically simply the sum of all symbols of all object files used to create that file.

> What generates a symbol?

All code (functions) and all data (variables, constants) defined in an object file that can be accessed from other object files definitely generate symbols in the object files.

However some linkers will remove some or all symbols from the resulting .EXE file because they are no longer needed after having created the .EXE file.

Most compilers also generate symbols for code and data that can only be accessed within an object file (such as "static" variables).

Many compilers generate symbols containing debugging information. Such symbols are ignored by the linker of course - and they are typically not shown in windbg.

Items that do not have an address in memory typically do not have a symbol: Data types (this includes classes!) do not have an address but every variable with that data type has its own address. The same is true for local variables (think about a function calling itself recursively to understand why).

> Why isn't there ConsoleApplication1!abc available?

Obviously you use a linker which can do optimization:

The linker "saw" that there was no "dummy address" (as mentioned above) which has to be replaced by the address `ConsoleApplication1!abc`. Therefore the linker "knew" that the function `abc()` was not used by the program so it did not include the function into the program.

Note that this is not possible for all object file formats.